Why does the form of the region affect the integration results?
I try to integrate $e^{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ on the region $x\ge y\ge 0 \&\& x^2+y^2\le4$. Obviously it can be solved by changing the variable.
Then I want to verify my result using the Mathematica with,
Integrate[Exp[Sqrt[x^2+y^2]],{x,y}\[Element]ImplicitRegion[x>=y>=0&&0<x^2+y^2<=4,{x,y}]]

However, it cannot solve it.

But if I use ParametricRegion instead of ImplicitRegion, it can give me the right anwser.
Integrate[Exp[Sqrt[x^2+y^2]],{x,y}\[Element]ParametricRegion[{r Cos[\[Theta]],r Sin[\[Theta]]},{{\[Theta],0,\[Pi]/4},{r,0,2}}]]


The region represented both ways is the same, why can Mathematica only calculate one of them?

I would say that changing the form of a region affects the integration process similar way like changing of variables. Why did you have to use the change of variables, isn't it still the same integral only in a different form? The answer is because otherwise you would not be able to solve it. Mathematica is not able to solve it with the given form of region and either it did not try to convert the region into a different form or it was not able to convert it.

@azerbajdzan:  I don't see how your comment "answers" the question other than to say "Mathematica cannot compute the integral expressed in that form."  Right?

Integrate[  Exp[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], {x, y} ∈    Disk[{0, 0}, 2, {0, π/4}]]
